# AWS Lambda & SES for New User Registration

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I ran across a Stored Procedure example in AWS's [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.BestPractices.html#Aurora.BestPractices.Lambda) with Lamba.  I am not familiar with Stored Procedures, but I was wondering if this example could be used for sending new user confirmation emails?  Is there a way to create a Stored Procedure to execute when a new row is inserted?

The workflow I was thinking was, as a new user is created, a column would define if the user is active or inactive.  Each use would then be assigned a UUID, which could be the anchor ID for sending an email for the confirmation link email (e.g. http://example.com/new-user-confirmation/).

What I am wondering is:

1) Is it possible to have such a stored procedure in AWS Aurora to call a lamba function upon an insert in a users table.

2) Is this a good/bad idea in general?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible (see below), but it may or may not be a good idea in your use case.

Personally, I would choose to have this lambda code invoked from middle layer, i.e. the layer between the UI (assuming a web interface), and the database, but that is a personal preference, not a requirement.

> **Invoking a Lambda Function from an Amazon Aurora DB Cluster**
>
> Note Integration with AWS Lambda is available for Amazon Aurora
>   version 1.8 and later. For more information on Aurora versions, see
>   Amazon Aurora Database Engine Updates. You can invoke an AWS Lambda
>   function from an Amazon Aurora DB cluster by calling the
>   mysql.lambda_async procedure. This approach can be useful when you
>   want to integrate your database running on Amazon Aurora with other
>   AWS services. For example, you might want to send a notification using
>   Amazon Simple Notification Service (Amazon SNS) whenever a row is
>   inserted into a specific table in your database.
>
> To invoke a Lambda function, you grant your Aurora DB cluster
>   permission to access AWS Lambda. You grant permission by creating an
>   IAM role with the necessary permissions, and then associating the role
>   with your DB cluster. You must also configure your Aurora DB cluster
>   to allow outbound connections to AWS Lambda. For details and
>   instructions on how to permit your Aurora DB cluster to communicate
>   with AWS Lambda on your behalf, see Authorizing Amazon Aurora to
>   Access Other AWS Services on Your Behalf.